# Svelte 3.52 and Typescript (ts)

Tags: web-development

Does anyone know how to run **Typescript** with Svelte 3.52?

It was bat file, but it wasn't anymore.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to start writing code in TS. But, all is in JS.

Answer (score 0):

From
[Svelte <3 TypeScript](https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-and-typescript):

> You can start a new Svelte TypeScript project using the [normal
> template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) and by running `node scripts/setupTypeScript.js` before you do anything else:
>
> ```
> npx degit sveltejs/template svelte-typescript-app
> cd svelte-typescript-app
> node scripts/setupTypeScript.js
> ```
>
> If you're a VS Code user, make sure you're using the (new) [official
> extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode),
> which replaces the popular extension by James Birtles.

Comment: Doesn't have 'scripts' folder. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should use `svelte-ts` instead of `svelte`.

`npm create vite@latest myapp -- --template svelte-ts`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).